# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 |

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, mobile

how to fix this ??

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A715F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1607)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1497)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1504)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1308)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1271)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:733)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i tried to delete gradle-wrapper.jar and change version to 7.2 : doe`your text`snt work :/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).